# Azure App Service Swap Task hindered by App Service IP Whitelist: Failed to update deployment history

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-appservice

I have recently enabled IP whitelisting on my pre-production environments and noticed the following issue.

When I run the `Azure App Service Manager` Task in Azure DevOps to Swap my deployment and production slot I get hit with a warning `##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)`.

This causes the site to throw a 500.30 and 503 errors when attempting to access the site after a swap.

This is easily fixed by then restarting the application, but of course the best flow would be to not have to have any downtime after a deployment slot swap.

#### DevOps service tag on whitelist

I figured the solution would be to include DevOps service tag on the whitelist of the pre-production environments.. But sadly that had no impact on the errors.

[image: The Azure DevOps service tag added to App Service whitelist.]

#### Full output of the release pipeline task.

```
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7051171Z ##[section]Starting: Swap CM slots
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7173325Z ==============================================================================
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7173625Z Task         : Azure App Service manage
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7173987Z Description  : Start, stop, restart, slot swap, slot delete, install site extensions or enable continuous monitoring for an Azure App Service
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7174442Z Version      : 0.200.0
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7174628Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7174919Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage
2022-05-19T07:16:02.7175256Z ==============================================================================
2022-05-19T07:16:03.7506005Z Warming-up slots
2022-05-19T07:16:04.1489337Z Swapping App Service 'my-site-as-cm-tst' slots - 'secondary' and 'production'
2022-05-19T07:17:52.5029319Z Swapped App Service 'my-site-as-cm-tst' slots - 'secondary' and 'production'
2022-05-19T07:17:59.5975474Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://my-site-secondary.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/151652944672891
2022-05-19T07:17:59.7169507Z ##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)
2022-05-19T07:17:59.7221693Z ##[section]Finishing: Swap CM slots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check the REST site scm.azurewebsites.net must have Allow All, i.e. no restriction.
Also, Same restrictions as ***.azurewebsites.net should be unchecked.

You may also refer to this detailed document on Slot Swap: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#what-happens-during-a-swap

Comment: Can confirm the answer was indeed the `Same restrictions as ***.azurewebsites.net` being checked where they should've been unchecked. Thank you very much!